# How to add new attributes to schema after the migration?

Tags: mysql, node.js, migration, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

currently I am working on a node.js project, and I found a problem while I was building the schema, usually, I use command line provided by http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/migrations.html to define my schema, which is `$ node_modules/.bin/sequelize model:generate --name User --attributes firstName:string,lastName:string,email:string`  , and after the `$ node_modules/.bin/sequelize db:migrate`, I can write these attributes into database. However, I am wondering how to add new attribute to schema after the migration, I searched and found this https://github.com/sequelize/cli/issues/133 is discussing this problem, but after I tried the solution and run `$ node_modules/.bin/sequelize db:migrate` again, it did not write the new attributes to the original schema, I don't understand where's the problem, below is my code, I am trying to add two attributes 'address'& 'height' into the user schema, can you guys give me some advice? Thank you!

```
'use strict';
module.exports = {
  up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    let migration = [];
    migrations.push(queryInterface.addColumn(
            'address',
            'height',
            {
                type: Sequelize.STRING,
              }
        ));

    return Promise.all(migrations);
    return queryInterface.createTable('Users', {
      id: {
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      },
      firstName: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
      },
      lastName: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
      },
      email: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
      },
      createdAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE,
      },
      updatedAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE,
      },
    });
  },

  down: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.dropTable('Users');
  }
};
```

Comment: Hi, this issue has been solved, you can use below link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46357533/how-to-add-delete-new-columns-in-sequelize-cli to solve that issue, also you can check the query part of sequelize to see the documents http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/query-interface.js~QueryInterface.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this issue has been solved, you can use below link [How to Add, Delete new Columns in Sequelize CLI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46357533/how-to-add-delete-new-columns-in-sequelize-cli) to solve that issue, also you can check the query part of sequelize to see the documents http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/query-interface.js~QueryInterface.html, The real answer should be

```
module.exports = {
  up: function (queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    return [
      queryInterface.addColumn(
        'users',
        'height',
        {
          type: Sequelize.STRING,
        }
      ),
      queryInterface.addColumn(
        'users',
        'address',
        {
          type: Sequelize.STRING,
        }
      )
    ];
  },

  down: function (queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    return [
      queryInterface.removeColumn('users', 'height'),
      queryInterface.removeColumn('users', 'address')
    ];
  }
};
```

and then you can type

```
sequelize migration:create --name add-height-and-address-to-user
sequelize db:migrate
```

to migrate new attributes into your model.