# Will the sequelize update method create new columns in a table, if i pass an object with more properties other than the ones existing in the table?

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js, hapi

Suppose i have a table, let's consider a table Book with columns, **title** and **pages**.
And now i am calling the update method on top of the table Book with an object having title, pages as well as price.
Will sequelize create a new column for the price property or, it will just ignore the price attribute.

Answer (score 0):

No, the update method is used for changing data in an existing entry. If you want to add a brand new column in an existing database without flushing it, you must first create a migration.

check this question out:
[How to Add, Delete new Columns in Sequelize CLI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46357533/how-to-add-delete-new-columns-in-sequelize-cli) and also read up on the migration documentation here:  [migration docks](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/migrations.html)

hope that helps!